# Running multiple Solr instances vs using classes

Tags: apache, search, elasticsearch, indexing, solr

So, on my current project, we have two classes - say apples and oranges. They relate to each other, users always have to buy apples, but they can add oranges to their apple purchase.

We are already indexing the apples and performing searches across them. We now want to set up a complementary "Would you like to add to your order?" type thing.

The question is whether to add these oranges to the existing index (full of apples), or create a new index? What are the performance implications? I presume we could eventually return both in the same query if they were in the same index, by doing something like `type: apples OR oranges`?

Comment: It's unclear how you want to use Oranges. Are you searching for them? Generally, if you're not searching for it, you don't need to bother putting it in your index at all, unless your index is also your primary data store. Perhaps there's a search you need to support like "Given a particular Apple, search for the Oranges that go with it?"

Comment: `Given a particular Apple, search for the Oranges that go with it?` -- yes, this is exactly what we need. In fact, it will be more like "given a particular apple, find all oranges within a 100km radius". So yes, we are indexing it to search over.

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat subjective question, so here are some deciding factors:

- If you need to query both at once, or expect to, use the same index. (Or collection, if SolrCloud - You actually can query two SolrCloud collections in a single query, but relevance ordering may be strange.)
- If the schema for Apples and Oranges is somewhat different, or you expect it to be, that's a point for different indexes
- A type:apples filter doesn't sound likely to eliminate much of your document set, compared to other criteria. It can be saved in the filterCache, which is fast, but I've had some odd performance results with unrestrictive filter queries combined with highly restrictive queries. The only concrete answer is to run tests on your specific index.
- There are some memory aspects of Solr/Lucene that scale with index size, not query result size. The larger your index, the more important GC tuning gets. This is a point for preferring different indexes, if you can.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Do you know of any guides for setting up multiple indices on one Solr instance?

Comment: There's nothing that says you can't run solrcloud on a single node, and that makes dealing with multiple indexes easier. If not, you'll probably be working with the core api: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CoreAdmin+API